# Is a COM object a C++ class?

Tags: c++, c, com

I've read two articles describing COM objects as being *basically* C++ classes. Is this true? Here's one of the articles I am reading: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13601/COM-in-plain-C

It describes a means for creating a COM object in C. COM enforces that the first members of this structure are certain function pointers.

I am not seeing the concrete correlation between COM objects and C++, although I can understand that relationship is easily understood.

Comment: In a word; no, and anyone that has ever had the pleasure of writing a COM object in native C will attest to that. C++ makes writing COM objects *much* easier due to the vtable layout, but you do not need C++ to write them. In fact, you don't even need C, as VB and C# engineers will happily acknowledge.

Comment: [The layout of a COM object](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/05/68017.aspx) article explains it quite well.

Comment: @JesseGood nice find. Man that brings back memories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO, this depends a little on how you define a COM object.  If a COM object is any object that is compatible with the COM Binary Interface, then whether or not the object is internally implemented in C++ is an implementation detail.  It can be implemented in C++, but it could also be implemented in all sorts of other ways, and it is largely irrelevant as long as you access it through the COM interface.

That being said, as Adam and WhozCraig pointed out, COM's Binary Interface was designed with MSVC's C++ compiler in mind.  Writing COM objects in MSVC C++ was the 'original' way to create COM objects.  So the two definitely have an interwoven history, and indeed the COM Binary Interface specification has a lot in common with how MSVC lays out C++ objects.  But, the MSVC compiler still has to generate COM bindings as an 'extra' compile step (e.g., the COM typelib, and C++ import headers so other C++ projects can import the COM library).

Answer (score 4):

COM specifies exactly how its objects are to be laid out: with the virtual function table pointer (aka vtable pointer) as the first member in the object.  It's designed so that the layout is identical to how the Microsoft compiler lays out C++ objects, so that you can have a C++ class that compiles identically to a manually defined C structure.

As long as you're using a Microsoft compiler, then yes, a COM object is basically a C++ class instance.  But if you're using a different compiler, you need to take special care to ensure that it lays out C++ objects in the same manner.  As long as you're not using multiple inheritance or virtual inheritance, *most* compilers will put the vtable first, so it will usually work, but some compilers put the vtable at the end.  Make sure to read your compiler's documentation and figure out if it's COM-compatible or not.

Answer (score 2):

The COM object specification was designed to utilize the already existing binary layout of a C++ object, so in that sense they're based on C++ classes.

The IDispatch interface was created to make it easier to use COM from languages that can't use C++ vtables. It adds an extra layer of indirection to a COM call.

Answer (score 0):

COM stands for Component Object Model. Its a library which is built using different types of components identified by class IDs (CLSIDs), which are Globally Unique Identifiers (GUIDs). Each COM component exposes its functionality through one or more interfaces. The different interfaces supported by a component are distinguished from each other using interface IDs (IIDs), which are GUIDs too.

Answer (score 0):

Adding another answer, since I think there's a few really useful things to know about both COM and C++ that the other answers didn't cover.

Perhaps three important things to get are:

- A COM object is really a *collection of COM interfaces*, which cooperate to give the appearance of having a shared COM object identity (you can QI from any interface to any other, and one of those interfaces is the one that you get back anytime you QI for IUnknown, aka the 'canonical unknown').
- A COM interface happens to have the same layout as a C++ object's vtable as implemented by MSVC - and all (AFAIK) windows compilers.
- COM is more focused on interfaces. C++ is more focused on classes.

The second of these is what makes it simple to implement COM objects in C++. But the first of these means there are many variations on the theme. So you could have:

- A single-interface COM object that is implemented in C++ as a class that implements one interface
- A single COM object with multiple interfaces that is implemented as a C++ class that implements several interfaces, using C++'s Multiple Inheritance.
- A single COM object with multiple interface that is implemented a *collection* of cooperating C++ object instances, perhaps one C++ class per COM interface; or one C++ class implementing most of the COM object's interfaces, and using helper C++ classes to implement infrequently used interfaces, perhaps creating those helper C++ classes only on the fly as needed! (Note that this is separate again from COM aggregation.)

This last case is particularly interesting, as it illustrates that a single COM object can map to several C++ objects in implementation. COM doesn't care, so long as you follow its rules (Specifically regarding refcounting, QI should be associative, reflexive and transitive, and all COM objects should have a Canonical IUnknown.)

Even though it's reasonably simple to implement a COM object in C++, you can't assume that any COM object you get your hands on is actually a C++ class behind the scenes: it could be implemented in C, assembler, or be a dynamically generated piece of code that's a wrapper for some C# code.

Keep in mind that C++ features such as RTTI and C++ exceptions are not part of COM, so you can't use them against an arbitrary COM object - unless of course you know it's actually one of your own C++ classes, in which case you are really using the object in its capacity as a C++ class, and not as a COM object.